# Sort a JSONArray in two time

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSONArray like this :

```
[{
    "Periode":203,
    "Annulé":0,
    "En_commande":0,
    "En_attente":100,
    "En_cours":0,
    "Perdu":0,
    "Terminé":0
},
{
    "Periode":204,
    "Annulé":0,
    "En_commande":0,
    "En_attente":500,
    "En_cours":0,
    "Perdu":500,
    "Terminé":0
},
{
    "Periode":205,
    "Annulé":0,
    "En_commande":1000,
    "En_attente":0,
    "En_cours":0,
    "Perdu":0,
    "Terminé":0
},
{
    "Periode":208,
    "Annulé":1000,
    "En_commande":0,
    "En_attente":0,
    "En_cours":0,
    "Perdu":0,
    "Terminé":0
},
{
    "En_attente":600,
    "En_commande":1000,
    "Perdu":2000,
    "Terminé":500,
    "En_cours":2000,
    "Annulé":1000
}]
```

The last object in this array correspond to the total of the others (Except the field "Periode").
So I want to sort the last object by their values and then sort all the other JSONObject in the same order than it.

I have no idea how to do that, a solution would be perfect but I take any research track or algo

the result wanted for my example :

```
[{
    "Periode":203,
    "Perdu":0,
    "En_cours":0,
    "En_commande":0,
    "Annulé":0,
    "En_attente":100,
    "Terminé":0
},
{
    "Periode":204,
    "Perdu":500,
    "En_cours":0,
    "En_commande":0,
    "Annulé":0,
    "En_attente":500,
    "Terminé":0
},
{
    "Periode":205,
    "Perdu":0,
    "En_cours":0,
    "En_commande":1000,
    "Annulé":0,
    "En_attente":0,
    "Terminé":0
},
{
    "Periode":208,
    "Perdu":0,
    "En_cours":0,
    "En_commande":0,
    "Annulé":1000,
    "En_attente":0,
    "Terminé":0
},
{
    "Perdu":2000,
    "En_cours":2000,
    "En_commande":1000,
    "Annulé":1000,
    "En_attente":600,
    "Terminé":500
}]
```

Comment: How order of elements in last objects related to other objects for sorting?

Comment: All the keys in the last object are present in the others

Comment: Suppose in last object, `Perdu` comes first, then how other elements should be sorted. Expected output can give a clear picture.

Comment: I updated my post. Check the wanted result

Comment: I don't understand why my proble is duplicate. I read the post and I don't see how to solve my problem with the answers. Can someone explain me if I missed something

Answer (score 0):

- Import gson:
  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0
- Convert your json to a class: (which is data in this example)
  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
- Convert your string json to array, sort it, and convert it back:

  ```
  Data[] data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data[].class);

  List<Data> datas = Arrays.asList(data);

  Collections.sort(datas, new Comparator<Data>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Data o1, Data o2) {

          if(o1.getPeriode() != null && o2.getPeriode() != null)
               return Integer.compare(o1.getPeriode(), o2.getPeriode());

          return Integer.compare(o1.getPerdu(), o2.getPerdu());
      }
  });

  data = datas.toArray(new Data[0]);
  String s = new Gson().toJson(data);
  System.out.println(s);
  ```